# Does the tropical semiring admit a universal property?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, tropical-geometry, semirings, tropical-arithmetic

Each of the rings $\mathbf{Q}$, $\mathbf{Z}_p$, $\mathbf{Q}_p$, $\mathbf{R}$ admits a universal construction: the rationals are the field of fractions of the integers: $\mathbf{Q}:=\mathrm{Frac}(\mathbf{Z})$; the $p$-adic integers $\mathbf{Z}_p$ and $p$-adic numbers $\mathbf{Q}_p$ are the completion of the rings $\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ with respect to the $p$-adic valuation; the ring $\mathbf{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbf{Q}$ with respect to the infinite valuation.

Some of these rings also have natural characterisations among one or other specific class of rings. For example, $\mathbf{R}$ is the terminal archimedean field, while $\mathbf{Q}$ is the initial characteristic zero field.

**Are there universal constructions or characterisations for the tropical semiring?**

To be more precise, there are four different semirings that are usually called "the" tropical semiring:

1. the set $\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ equipped with $\max$ as addition and $+$ as multiplication;
2. the set $\mathbf{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ with the same operations;
3. each of the above examples, but with $-\infty$ instead of $\infty$ and with $\min$ instead of $\max$ as the addition.

However, this last point does not matter: the semirings $\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $\mathbf{N}\cup\{-\infty\}$ are canonically isomorphic, and similarly for the version involving $\mathbf{R}$. So it suffices to focus on $\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $\mathbf{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ only.

The semirings $\mathbf{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ are both *idempotent semirings*, meaning that $a+a=a$ for each  element $a$ in these rings. In addition, $\mathbf{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ carries a natural topology making addition and multiplication into continuous morphisms, turning it into a *topological semiring*, characterised as the unique one making the map $-\log:\mathbf{R}_{\geq0}\to\mathbf{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ into a homeomorphism. So does $\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, carrying the order topology, which agrees with both the subspace topology with respect to $\mathbf{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ and the one-point compactification topology.

My specific questions are:

1. Are there universal *constructions* of $\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $\mathbf{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ as

   - semirings?
   - topological semirings?
2. Are there *characterisations* of $\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $\mathbf{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ as being *universal* with respect to some property among:

   - all semirings?
   - idempotent semirings?
   - topological semirings?

---

So far, there are the following *universal characterisations* of $\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$:

- [Schweber](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245616/universal-constructions-and-characterisations-of-the-tropical-semiring-among-all#comment8826039_4245616). The initial idempotent semiring with a nonzero additively indecomposable annihilator.
- [Dave](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/sampayne/pdf/Math648Lecture1.pdf). The semiring of ideals of any discrete valuation ring.

Comment: Crossposted: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245616).

Comment: It isn't true that $(\mathbb N \cup \infty,\max,+)$ and $(\mathbb N \cup -\infty,\min,+)$ are isomorphic: both have infinity as the absorbing element w.r.t. $(\max, +)$ and $(\min,+)$ respectively, so an isomorphism would map $\infty \mapsto -\infty$ and $\mathbb N \mapsto \mathbb N$. However, $0$ is an identity element for $\max$ in the former ring, while the latter doesn't have an identity element for $\min$.

Comment: There would be an isomorphism if you considered $\mathbb Z \cup \infty$ instead of $\mathbb N \cup \infty$. Perhaps you meant to ask about it. Perhaps you also wanted to ask a question about $(\mathbb N \cup \infty, \min, +)$, because it's the semiring in the definition of discrete valuation, and maybe about $(\mathbb N \cup -\infty, \max, +)$ for symmetry.